proving a fact in a rank of a tree for $\mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}$
Let $T \subset \mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}$ be a tree. Define $T' := T \setminus \{t \in T: \lnot \exists s \in T(t \subsetneq s)\}$ i.e. $T'$ removes all the leafs. Define $T^0 := T$ and $T^{\alpha + 1} := (T^\alpha)'$ and $T^{\lambda} := \bigcap_{\alpha < \lambda}T_\alpha$ where $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal. Define the rank of $t \in T$ as the countable ordinal $\alpha$ such that $t \in T^\alpha \setminus T^{\alpha + 1}$ otherwise set the rank to infinity(i.e. $\infty$ is bigger than any countable ordinal). Define the rank of $T$ as the rank of $\emptyset$.
Fixing a $t \in T$, intuitively I see why $\text{Rank}(t) = \sup \{\text{Rank}(t \cdot n) + 1: t \cdot n \in T\}$(note $\cdot$ is concatenation, it won't let me use \string^). I can prove this in the finite case, but I can't find the proof overall (consider when there are an infinite amount of t). I can see that $\text{Rank}(t \cdot n) + 1 \leq \text{Rank}(t)$.
Similarly, I am trying to prove that $\text{Rank}(T) = \sup \{\text{Rank}(T_n) + 1: n \in T\}$ where $T_n := \{t \in \mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}: n \cdot t \in T\}$

$\frown$ is \frown
